# Is it possible to query the @@DBTS on a database other than the current database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, timestamp

For a rigorous marker of the source database state, I'd like to capture the @@DBTS
of an external database in a sproc.  Yeah, I think I could issue

> `USE ExternalDB
>
> GO
>
>
>
> SELECT @myVarbinary8 = @@DBTS
>
> GO
>
>
>
> USE OriginalDB
>
> GO`

but, even if I could, it seems ugly.

For now, I've embedded a scalar-valued function in the source database to invoke the

SET @Result = SELECT @@DBTS

which worked fine until I forgot to ask the DBA to grant the appropriate rights for a new user, which crashed a process.

Something akin to

> `SELECT ExternalServer.dbo.@@DBTS` 
>
> (I know that doesn't work).

See   [MSDN @@DBTS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187366(SQL.90).aspx)

> @@DBTS (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns the value of the current timestamp data type for the current database. 
>
> This timestamp is guaranteed to be unique in the database.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to put that scalar function in the master database and mark it as system object. that way it gets called in the context of the current database
see here for more info:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/01/18/58287.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure in your *"other"* database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDatabaseTimestamp AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT @@DBTS AS CurrentRowversion, MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION() AS ActiveRowversion
```

And then from your current database you can call:

```
EXECUTE ExternalDB.dbo.GetDatabaseTimestamp;
```

Comment: Just a style/practice thing...

The functional programming side of my brain likes to stay away from 
unnecessary side-effects (changing the database context w/ USE).

At least w/ sp_executesql, the context is guaranteed to be the original w/o the need to switch it back

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info, Mladen, that tip is good to know :)

But while that helps me call a function residing in master from in the current database context "ContextCurrent", what I really want is to be able to call the scalar-valued function from the context of the source database "ContextSource".

While in general, I have my reservations against dynamic sql, I ended up using it here as follows.

`DECLARE @sourceDbName  nvarchar(128)

SET     @sourceDbName    = N'sbaportia1'



DECLARE @strQuery      nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @parmDefn      nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @DbtsCapture   varbinary(8)

SET    @strQuery =

    '

              N' ' +  N'USE' + N' ' + @sourceDbName + N' '

         + N' ' +  N'SELECT @dbtsCapture = min_active_rowversion()'

    '



SET @parmDefn =

    N'

           @dbName         varchar(128),

           @dbtsCapture    varbinary(8) OUTPUT

    '



EXEC sp_executesql    @strQuery

                    ,@parmDefn

                     ,@dbName        = 'autobahn'

                    ,@dbtsCapture    = @dbtsCapture  OUTPUT



SELECT @dbtsCapture`

Furthermore, since sp_executesql runs in a separate thread,
the database context within the script below will be 
automatically be the same upon the exit of sp_executesql
as upon the entry of sp_executesql.
(I learned waaayy too much about sp_executesql in the early 2000's.)